# Is there such a thing as an ascending 5th descending 3rd sequence?

Tags: voice-leading

So basically moving up a 5th and then down a third, up a 5th and down a third etc.

My figured bass exercise by David Ledbetter has it but my other textbooks make no mention of such a sequence.

Comment: Is there such a thing?  Well yes, you just described it.  Do you want to know whether it was ever used or commonly used by common practice composers?  Does your figured bass book have everything in root position?  If not, what are the figures?

Comment: For now my figured bass book only talks of root position chords becuase I am on page 4 but it talks about mainting sequences in the right hand chord shapes instead of trying to find the closest right hand chord shape and in  this case there appears this sequence of an ascending 5th/descending 3rd and I have not seen such a sequence before. My textbooks show sequences and even "rare" sequences but this one does not appear anywhere.

Comment: There is a +3/-5 sequence, which is basically the Pachelbel sequence but with applied dominants (C, E, Am, C, F, etc.). But I'm not too familiar with a +5/-3.

Comment: I feel like there can be any conceivable sequence of any conceivable combination, as long as it repeats—am I wrong? How convenient it is is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

In *Music in the Galant Style*, Gjerdingen describes a sequence he calls *monte romanesca*...

[image]

Your sequence, if I understood your meaning, could be...

[image]

...which is very similar. It skips the `ii V/ii` iteration, but still arrives at `iii V/iii`, when your sequence moves to `V V/V` it remains strongly in the tonal center.

Keep in mind with the Gjerdingen schemata/sequences the specific scale degree roots matter, you cannot transpose willy-nilly to other scale degree positions.